# How to Toggle the Visibility of an Item in a StackPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a ListBox which contains a StackPanel of two items, an Image and a Textblock. At the user's request, I would like to be able to toggle the visibility of the TextBlock on or off, thus only showing the Images. As it is now, the Image and TextBlock combination for each item is stacked vertically, and the Image is a perfect square (which ultimately creates a rectangular shape when the TextBlock is shown under each image). When the user wishes to hide the TextBlock, I would like to have the ListBox show only the StackPanel items as uniform squares for the Images (hopefully that made sense).

What I have is as follows

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxEffects" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="{Binding}"
                     toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" 
                         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="159" ItemHeight="Auto" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  >
                                <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="155" Height="155" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="{Binding TextBlockVisibility}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

And in the ApplicationBar created in the code behind is where I have a menu item which will allow a user to select his or her preference on showing or hiding the TextBlock under each Image

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        ApplicationBarMenuItem showFilterNamesMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
        if (Settings.ShowFilterNames.Value)
            showFilterNamesMenuItem.Text = "Hide names";
        else
            showFilterNamesMenuItem.Text = "Show names";
        showFilterNamesMenuItem.Click += showFilterNamesMenuItem_Click;
        ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(showFilterNamesMenuItem);
    }

void showFilterNamesMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Settings.ShowFilterNames.Value)
        {
            ((ApplicationBarMenuItem)ApplicationBar.MenuItems[0]).Text = "Hide names";
            Settings.ShowFilterNames.Value = false;

            //Toggle the text block visibility to show text here
        }
        else
        {
            ((ApplicationBarMenuItem)ApplicationBar.MenuItems[0]).Text = "Show names";
            Settings.ShowFilterNames.Value = true;

            //Toggle the text block visibility to hide text here
        }        
    }
```

And a check is performed when the page is navigated to so that the TextBlock's under each image can be shown or hidden appropriately

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (Settings.ShowFilterNames.Value)     
            //Show the TextBlocks here
        else
            //Hide the TextBlocks here
    }
```

As far as I can tell the above implementation does toggle the menu item text correctly and saves the user's preference so that upon returning the menu item text is displayed according to the last selection the user chose, but I am unsure of how to change the visibility of the TextBlock underneath each image in the ListBox?

EDIT**

BooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs

```
//Error on BooleanToVisibilityConverter stating does not implement interface member 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert(object, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter   
{   
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)      
    {      
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;      
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)      
    {      
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;      
    }   
}
```

and in XAML

```
xmlns:common="clr-namespace:TestApp.Common"

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConv" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<ListBox Name="ListBoxEffects" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="{Binding}"
                     toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" 
                         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="159" ItemHeight="Auto" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  >
                                <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="155" Height="155" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="{Binding IsTextBlockVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConv}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this method to find out your Textblock for each ListBoxItem

```
public static T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            try
            {
                int childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
                if (childCount == 0)
                    return null;

                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        return (T)child;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                        if (result != null)
                            return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This Method will return First element of specified type from your DataTemplate. And allows you to work with that indivisual element.

For this You can use following code snippet

```
    for(i=0;i<ListBoxEffects.count;i++)
    {
     ListBoxItem item = ListBoxEffects.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
     StackPanel TargetStackPanel = common.FindFirstElementInVisualTree<StackPanel>(item);
     TextBlock TargetTextBlock= TargetStackPanel.Children[1] as TextBlock;
     TargetTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     ListBoxEffects.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

Use the above code to show or hide the textblocks respectively Just by changing the line

```
 TargetTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

or

```
 TargetTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Visibility` property is an enum of type `Visibility`. This would be quite a bit easier if it were a boolean, but it's not.

You should define a static resource to instantiate a `BooleanToVisibility` converter, then bind the `Visibility` property to a boolean property in your DataContext. Here's a working example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConv" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Hide me" Visibility="{Binding IsTextBlockVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConv}}" />
        <Button Content="Toggle TextBlock" Name="ToggleItButton" Click="ToggleItButton_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private bool m_IsTextBlockVisible = true;
    public bool IsTextBlockVisible {
        get { return m_IsTextBlockVisible; }
        set { m_IsTextBlockVisible = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsTextBlockVisible"); }
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void ToggleItButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        IsTextBlockVisible = !IsTextBlockVisible;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble implementing your solution, I am programming for the Windows Phone so it is very similar. Did you create a class for your converter that you reference in xaml? I get an error on `<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConv" />`. I tried to create a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` class but I am having trouble with that as well. I added some edits above.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create two `DataTemplate`. One `DataTemplate` with name and the other one without name.

XAML:

```
<Window ...
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateWithName">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  >
                <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="155" Height="155" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateWithoutName">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  >
                <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="155" Height="155" />               
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="tbName" Content="Name" Click="tbName_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxEffects" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 Grid.Row="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateWithName}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel ItemWidth="159" ItemHeight="Auto" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>           
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void tbName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tbName.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        ListBoxEffects.ItemTemplate = this.FindResource("TemplateWithoutName") as DataTemplate;
    }
    else
    {
        ListBoxEffects.ItemTemplate = this.FindResource("TemplateWithName") as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, addition to your question:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private object GetVisibility(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is bool))
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        bool objValue = (bool)value;
        if (objValue)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return GetVisibility(value);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}
```